# Form Reset Can't Clear jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

In ASP.NET, I've got a user control which appears on each page presenting the user with some options for searching.  The control contains a 'Reset' button to clear all the fields and I'm trying to handle that all client side.  The control contains, textboxes, date controls, dropdownlists - and a jQuery autocomplete.  I'm able the clear-out every field except the autocomplete with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= btnReset.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        $(".txtClear").val('');
        $(".ddlClear").attr('selectedIndex', 0);
        $(".datepicker").val('__/__/____');

        var source = $("#<%= acSCAC.ClientID %>").autocomplete("option", "source");
        $("#<%= acSCAC.ClientID %>").autocomplete("option", "source", [""]);
        $("#<%= acSCAC.ClientID %>").val("");
        $("#<%= acSCAC.ClientID %>").autocomplete("option", "source", source);

        return false;
    });
});
```

You'll note one of my failed attempts at clearing out the autocomplete near the end.

I want it set as it was when the page first loaded - with nothing in it.

Is this not possible?

Comment: Is this an autocomplete function that you built or are you referring to the browser's autocomplete functionality?

Comment: I'm referring to the jQuery UI autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could just use the destroy method or set the options to an empty array and then reapply the autocomplete data that you want to appear there. (More on the methods tab on this page - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

```
$("#<%= acSCAC.ClientID %>").autocomplete("destroy"); //returns input to init status
```

or

```
$("#<%= acSCAC.ClientID %>").autocomplete({"source": [""]}); //clears the autocomplete options array
```

Followed by the following to reload the options array with data from the original source array

```
$("#<%= acSCAC.ClientID %>").autocomplete({"source": originalsourcearray});
```

I also put a sample of what I have done up on jsfiddle.net - http://jsfiddle.net/tFkjA/15/

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't see that as an option, adding it gives: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Comment above was in reference to flushCache - This kind of breaks the model, given that it's packaged inside a user control and doing this, I assume, would mean re-adding the source and the select handler in the reset code when it's already handled inside the UC.  All just to clear a text field.

Comment: Ok, so I assume you are setting the source for the autocomplete when the page loads. If destroy is too much you can reset to your original source by $("#id").autocomplete({"source": insertsourcearrayhere});

Comment: The source is set within the UC using a property set on the UC.  I think I was attempting to accomplish what you suggest with the code near the end of my sample, but maybe I got it wrong...

Comment: Whereas I think the method you are using .autocomplete("option", "source", source) should work I have not had any success. The line I suggested .autocomplete({"source":source}) works for me.

Comment: First LeRoy - thanks for all your input.  Unfortunately, your second solution didn't work either.  Even less fortunate is that I'm an idiot.  acSCAC is the user control which contains the original jQuery, and the field for it to act on.  Calling all this jQ on acSCAC is useless because it *should* be called on the input within acACAC.

Changing the code to call .val('') on that input absolutely does the trick.